# python makedirs permission denied

Tags: python, apache, mkdir

I have an apache httpd server running python code using django framework and mod_wsgi.
I my view.py i need to make a subprocess call to execute another python file which in the process needs to create some directories.

However, I am getting OSERROR 13: Permission denied no matter where I try to create the directory.

Only creating a directory in /tmp is successfull.

Can anyone guide me on how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!!!

**EDIT:**
I found the answer in serverfault.com. Here it is for reference
apache2 runs under root, but it forks processes which run under 'www-data' group.
So create a directory where you want to create files/directories

```
sudo mkdir /srv/www/writable
```

Change the group

```
sudo chgrp www-data /srv/www/writable
```

Grant the group write access

```
sudo chmod g+w /srv/www/writable
```

And you are done. Now you can create any files/directories in this directory using a script run by apache2

Comment: You obviously have a permissions problem due to apache running as a user account different from the one owning the parent directory you are trying to create new directories in.

Comment: Yeah i can make that out. I installed apache using apt-get and when i do ps aux|grep apache2 i see apache2 running under root user...

Comment: The main apache thread runs as root, but it forks children that usually switch to another user, generally www-data.

Comment: Yes I also see apache2 running under www-data...so does that mean i need to change owner/group of my directory to www-data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in serverfault.com. Here it is for reference

apache2 runs under root, but it forks processes which run under 'www-data' group. So create a directory where you want to create files/directories

sudo mkdir /srv/www/writable
Change the group

sudo chgrp www-data /srv/www/writable
Grant the group write access

sudo chmod g+w /srv/www/writable
And you are done. Now you can create any files/directories in this directory using a script run by apache2

Answer (score 3):

Might be worth adding that this can also be achieved in Python

```
import os
import pwd

path = '/var/www/myapp/foo/'
if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path) # creates with default perms 0777
        uid, gid =  pwd.getpwnam('root').pw_uid, pwd.getpwnam('www-data').pw_uid
        os.chown(path, uid, gid) # set user:group as root:www-data
```

Comment: Additionally, os.makedirs is supposed to set permissions at 0777 by default, but I have found this is not always the case.  To explicitly do this do:  os.chmod(path, 0777)

Comment: "I found this is not always the case" .... that's because on Unix `umask` is applied on the creation mode when creating file-system objects.  Plus, 0777 is a  bad choice for security reasons, which is why `umask` exists in the 1st place.

Comment: python os getpwnam is probably deprecated since it's not in the doc